# Document picker is not working in react native

Tags: react-native-native-module

[image]I am currently facing issue with react native document picker in my react native app .

I attached screenshot for your referenced.

RNDocumentPicker -Native module is not available.

Answer (score 1):

This is because it is not linked with Native Code, add the below code and check

In project settings.gradle

```
include ':react-native-document-picker'
project(':react-native-document-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-document-picker/android')
```

In Build.gradle add

```
implementation project(':react-native-document-picker')
```

in MainApplication add

```
 protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage(),
            new DocumentPickerPackage() // Add package 
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to link react-native-document-picker to native.

1. Stop the Metro server
2. run `react-native-document-picker`
3. run `react-native run-android`

That should solve the issue.